# JQUERY: Accessing element cousin by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I have the following html code:

```
<li class="grey">
    <div class="row">
       <button id="test" style="width:50%;" class="btn btn-blue-white cartBtn">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <a href="#" class="checkoutLink" style="margin-top:-10px;font-size:small">Go To Checkout</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

When I load the page, I hide the checkout link button until the user clicks "add to cart". After they click add to cart my javascript looks like this:

```
 $('.cartBtn').click(function () {
           //do stuff for preprocessing
            var url = "../Store/AddToCart";
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                data: {
                    //add data
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success == true) {
                       $(this).closest('li').find('.checkoutLink').show();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

the link never shows back up. I have also tried using

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('.checkoutLink').show()
```

as well and had no luck. How do i use jquery to get this anchor tag and make it visible.

Comment: its reaching the code, i have put in log statements and see them in there

Comment: what do you want to display?

Comment: In your `success` function `this` refers to `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `this`, when called from within the success function it no longer refers to the outer `this`. Create a variable outside of Ajax that refers to the original `this`.

```
    $('.cartBtn').click(function () {
              var $this = $(this);
               //do stuff for preprocessing
                var url = "../Store/AddToCart";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    data: {
                        //add data
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success == true) {
                           $this.closest('li').find('.checkoutLink').show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. I had tried doing something similar but I guess omitted the $  selector when i stored it in a  variable

Comment: The $ before $this shouldn't matter, but without it, `this` is a reserved word so that would cause an issue. If it worked, please feel free to accept it as the answer.

Comment: it wont let me until another 6 minutes. I wasnt using the protected word this, i was using var button instead. Not sure why it wasnt working.

Comment: It should also be noted that `$.ajax()` also has the option for `context`, which if you set it as `context: this`, the context in the callbacks will match.